# Understanding input dimentions, SoftmaxWithLoss and labels in Caffe

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, softmax

I'm trying to use my own trained network with my own data from C++. I trained and tested network on ".jpg" data with `ImageData` layers and then implemented basic caffe example "classification.cpp" to pass images through memory one-by-one. As the result I need to know the prob for 2 classes:
1 - object,
2 - environment.

My input layer for the regular purposes looks like:

```
layer {
    name: "data"
    top:  "data"
    top:  "label"
    type: "Input"
    input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 256 dim: 256 }}
}
```

Output layers:

```
layer {
    name: "fc6"
    top:  "fc6"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    bottom: "drop5"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 2
        weight_filler {
            type: "xavier"
            std: 0.1
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "prob"
    top:  "prob"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "fc6"
    bottom: "label"
}

layer {
    name: "accuracy"
    top:  "accuracy"
    type: "Accuracy"
    bottom: "fc6"
    bottom: "label"
    include {
        phase: TEST
    }
}
```

In the testing phase, the net has achieved accuracy=0.93, but now in regular use with C++ I can't figure out some basic concept and get an error while parsing the model.

```
Check failure stack trace:
...
caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Reshape()
caffe::Net<>::Init()
caffe::Net<>::Net()
...
Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (1 vs. 196608) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
```

Ok, 1x3x256x256 = 196608, but why I need this label count?
I have a file "labels.txt" as in the example "classification.cpp":

```
environment
object
```

Why labels != classes?
What should I do with SoftmaxWithLoss and input dimentions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define the `shape` for label, I assume you only have a single label per image. Thus

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  top:  "data"
  top:  "label"
  type: "Input"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 256 dim: 256 }
                shape: { dim: 1 dim: 1 }}  # one label per image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I try to use your layer structure, I get: `Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 51:21: Non-repeated field "input_param" is specified multiple times.`

Comment: Thanks, @Shai, it works, looks like i begin to solve following mismatch problem)